# django model Field for content that could be either a video or an image

Tags: django-model-field

I would like to define a django model Field that could be either an image or a video.
I Thought about using the image field and modifying the validator to accept also video files.
but what should I do with width and height attributes in case the field contains a video?

the other solution would be to use a FileField but looking into the django fields.files.py I see there is a lot more in the imagefield than just the width and height.

What would be the solution?